# Any specific rule to assign VersionName in Android?

Tags: android, version

I have updated my Android App last 7 times but till now I am assigning `VersionName` as per my wish. But, now I want to know if there is any specific rule or method to assign `VersionName` to Android App.
Please give me brief details if something is there.

Comment: Check this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_versioning

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not exactly rules but recommendations:

> 1. Since it is only shown to the User, it can be any String.
> 2. But like almost all the apps, it is better to follow **major.minor.point** format.

**e.g:**

> 1.0.0 to 1.0.1 for a bug fix
>
> 1.0.0 to 1.2.0 for any new feature
>
> 1.0.0 to 2.0.0 for a major design change, like supporting tablets etc..

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I was reading wiki posted by @Niko. Same thing. So, now I will keep this in mind when updating new version of my app. :)

Answer (score 0):

You already know what version is, now I'm telling about Android.
In Android, if you upgrade your version, then your old database get deleted and onUpgrade() method is called if you have used Database in your app. Similarly version change updates many things.
Generally developers increase version when they add new functionality. And if you update your app in mobile, then old apk get deleted and new get installed.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But this is not what i asked.